# ShowViewModel, passing different parameters to the same viewmodel

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to pass different objects to the same viewmodel using ShowViewModel. I've tried serializing with a derived class but without success. E.g.

```
// Two different subclasses extending MySuperClass 
MySubClass1 parameter1 = new MySubClass1();
MySubClass2 parameter2 = new MySubClass2();
//  Passing in either of the subclasses to the same viewmodel
ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>(parameter1);
/// OR
ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>(parameter2);

// Inside MyViewModel, Init is triggered but myParameter is null
public void Init(MySuperClass myParameter)
{          
}
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things you can pass presently are simple structures like ints and strings.  You could serialize your object to a string using newtonsoft and then reconstruct!

Comment: Thanks, I found this example explaining what you suggested  http://pmichaels.net/2014/07/13/mvvm-cross-basics-passing-complex-parameters-during-navigation/ another method would be to pass it through the IOC container as suggested in the comments in the link.